# Encryption and decryption method that produces alphanumeric only in C#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

As the title says : I need c# encryption method that produces alphanumeric cipher text from plaintext .I'd prefer if it takes passphrase if that's applicable here.

thanks

Comment: Hi abdul. Your question is too broad. There are lots of encryption methods. Stackoverflow is not thought for others to solve your homework: Google a little bit, read and try a bit. If you've done so, please let us know what you have tried so far and where you're stuck. As for alphanumeric characters, base-64 encoding could be used to transform the binary output of an encryption algorithm.

Comment: This is not a homework . What I wanted was just a method to encrypt some text to alphanumeric text without going into details of encryption . It was only for some texting I'm using .Thanks for the comment .

Answer (score 0):

You could use AES and then use Base36 class to convert it to a alphanumeric string. 
Example: `Base36.ByteArrayToBase36String(byteArray)`

To learn how to encrypt/decrypt with AES click [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt)

Comment: In what namespace Base36 is ?

Comment: Don't think there is a Base36 included in C#. However you can create your own or use this one: [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10619/Base-type-for-NET-C)

Answer (score -1):

I eventually used this :

```
this.textBox1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext));
```

Comment: That might obfuscate your text (make it harder to read), but it's absolutely not encryption.

Comment: I just hate it when people around here pretend to be so smart !!